# How to add search filters to the last page in a recyclerview that is per page?

Tags: android-studio

**I am doing a search filter by identity document in a Recyclerview that is per page, the problem is that at the time of making the filter it only looks for the first 10 that is the current page. How would I filter the search from the current page to the last page?**

**RecyclerActasAdapter.java**

```
  @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemsMostrados.size();
    }

    public void filtrar(String query) {
        this.itemsMostrados = new ArrayList<>();

        if (query.length() == 0) {
            itemsMostrados = listaActas;
            layoutResultados.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            ActasActivity actas= new ActasActivity();
            for (Datum data: listaActas) {
                if (data.getBeneficiario().getNumDocumento().contains(query)
                    //|| (data.getBeneficiario().getNombre().toLowerCase() + " " + data.getBeneficiario().getApellido().toLowerCase()).contains(text.toLowerCase())
                    || (data.getBeneficiario() != null ? data.getBeneficiario().getNombre() : "No registra" + " " + data.getBeneficiario() != null ? data.getBeneficiario().getApellido() : "No registra").contains(query)
                    //|| data.getPoblacion().getNombre().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())
                    //|| data.getMunicipio().getMunicipio().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())
                    ) {
                    itemsMostrados.add(data);

                }
            }

            layoutResultados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtResults.setText(itemsMostrados.size() + "");

        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void actualizar() {
        itemsMostrados = listaActas;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**ActasActivity.java**

**In this activity I try to create the condition to filter search to the last page but still continue to filter only the first 10 of the current page**

```
  public void obtenerActas(boolean inicializar) {

        if (inicializar) {
            current_page = 1;
            last_page = 1;
            last_size_pages = 0;
        }

        final Promise<RespuestaActasDTO, BusinessException, RespuestaActasDTO> mPromise = actasService.obtenerActas(current_page);
        mPromise.done(result -> {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            actualizarListadoActas(result, inicializar);

            if (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });
        mPromise.fail(error -> {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            Toast.makeText(mContexto, "Ocurrió un error consultando las actas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    }

    public void actualizarListadoActas(RespuestaActasDTO respuestaActasDTO, boolean inicializar) {

        // logica para controlar la pagina a consumir y saber cual es la ultima pagina
        last_page = respuestaActasDTO.getLastPage();

        //SI PAGINA ACTUAL ES MENOR QUE ULTIMA PAGINA
        if (current_page < last_page) {
            current_page++;//ENUMEREME DESDE LA PAGINA ACTUAL

        }

        if (actasAdapter == null || inicializar) {
            listaActas = new ArrayList<>();
            listaActas = respuestaActasDTO.getData();

            actasAdapter = new RecyclerActasAdapter(mContexto, listaActas, layoutResultados, txtResults);
            recyclerViewActas.setAdapter(actasAdapter);
            scrollListener.resetState();
        } else {
            //página actual <   última página
            if (current_page < last_page) {
                listaActas.addAll(respuestaActasDTO.getData());
                actasAdapter.actualizar();

                agregarUltimaConsulta = true;
            } else if (current_page == last_page) {
                if (agregarUltimaConsulta) {
                    agregarUltimaConsulta = false;
                    last_size_pages = respuestaActasDTO.getData().size();
                    ultimaLista = respuestaActasDTO.getData();

                    listaActas.addAll(ultimaLista);
                    actasAdapter.actualizar();
                } else if (last_size_pages != respuestaActasDTO.getData().size()) {
                    // limpiar ultimos registros para volverlos a agregar

                    ultimaLista = respuestaActasDTO.getData();
                    last_size_pages = respuestaActasDTO.getData().size();

                    listaActas.addAll(ultimaLista);
                    actasAdapter.actualizar();
                }
            }
        }
        // Logical END to control the page to consume and know which is the last page ------>>>>


        if (agregarEventoBuscar) {
            agregarEventoBuscar = false;
            // buscador
            inputBuscar.setOnQueryTextListener( new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    actasAdapter.filtrar(inputBuscar.getQuery().toString() );
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    return false;
                }
            } );

        }
```

**Observation: I only filter the query if I scroll to the last page, Thanks for your support**